# System intact, grub broken

Tags: debian, boot, grub2

I updated from wheezy to Jessie, everything went smoothly, until I restarted. When it booted back up, all I got was grub rescue (error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod') not found. ls gives me (hd0) (hd0,msdos1). ls (hd0,msdos1) is a blank line. Nothing in it. I booted from a live CD and tried running boot repair, but that failed at "grub-pc purge cancelled". I mounted the drive. Everything seems to be there. I chrooted in, purged grub, and reinstalled grub. No change. I have the exact same issue. I completely purged grub, without reinstalling. Still no change. I am at a loss, I do not know how to fix this, or even how to continue troubleshooting. Any help would be appreciated. (I know this is highly specific but I have searched everywhere.)

As requested `grub-install /dev/sda` from chroot yields:

```
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

`update-grub` yields:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-686-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-686-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-586
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-586
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-686-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-686-pae
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdb1. Check your device.map.
done
```

`/dev/sdb` seems to be my live CD.

Edit:

I used the super grub livecd, and now I can boot into Debian. From the operating system, I removed my livecd, then tried running `grub-install /dev/sda` and `update-grub`. When I reboot, I end up at the same grub rescue screen.

Comment: Is your /boot is on a separated partition?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell

Comment: Does `/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod` exist? Is there only one hdd?

Comment: From within the os yes, and yes.

Comment: please add the full output of `grub-install /dev/sda` to your queston.

Comment: Will do when I get into work.

Comment: I edited it as requested.

Comment: it seems to be ok. `update-grub`?

Comment: It also produces normal output (I'll post when I get in). I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Posted `update-grub`

Comment: From the grub command line, do: `root=(hd0,msdos1)` then `ls /`. What does that give you?

Comment: Just a blank line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simply and effective way to reinstall grub in your PC without complications is with the Boot-Repair-Disk utility (here is the download page: https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/latest/download), this is a live system that have tools for reinstalling the grub bootloader.

Steps: just download, burn in a USB with unetbootin or etcher and boot in your PC, when the system start you will see a windows with two options, select the one that says "recommended repair", now connect to internet (it will download the grub packages that corresponds to your system, Debian in your case), let the program analyse your partitions and just follow the steps, you will solve the problem in less than 5 minutes.
When you finish, reboot and make a "sudo grub-update" in a terminal on Debian, voila! Grub fully installed and configured again.

Another tool that can help you is Super Grub2 Rescue (here is the link: https://www.supergrubdisk.org/), weighs less than 20MB, this will help you to boot directly in Debian without installing grub.

Answer (score 0):

Try running: `echo "(hd0)     /dev/sda" > /boot/grub/device.map`

Comment: From grub, from the live CD, or from the live CD in chroot?

Comment: Ran it from within chroot, since that's the only thing that made sense. Still the same error.